# how do I transfer from watch only wallet to my other wallets

Tags: watch-only

I have a watch only wallet with BTC in there how do I transfer to another wallet. I don't seem to have a key is that possible? I can find it on blockchain but can't seem to do any transfers.

Answer (score 1):

That's what "watch-only" means. You are only watching the balance and can't spend it. You've likely added only the address to the wallet—which anybody else could have done as well since the address is public information.

If the address is your own, check the wallet that you created the address with. That's the one that can spend it. To spend the coins, you have to have the private key.

If you actually don't have the private key, you don't have the ability to spend the coins. If nobody else has it either, the coins are lost.