# How can I get a private key for this address

Tags: fraud, private-blockchains

[image: screenshot of the wallet]

Is it possible for me to withdraw my bitcoin I invested here?
I don't have the private key

Comment: Why do you not have the private key? In general, there is no known way to figure out the private key, given a specific bitcoin address. Bitcoins security depends on this.

Comment: Okay. I invested my bitcoins in someone's miner. He requested for me a new miner and told me to fund . so that he can configure it with the miner afterwards he told me to change my password..

Comment: Right now I want to withdraw my bitcoins I invested but he is asking me to pay him so that he can give me my private key..

Comment: The amount he is asking me to pay for the private key is 10 times what I invest. I invested $50BTC. Now for the key he wants me to pay him $500

Comment: This is a scam. Mining does not work that way, if you deposit more money you will not see it returned. Changing your password means nothing if the attacker had access to your account in the past, he will have copied down your recovery phrase, and will be able to recreate your wallet on another device, without needing any passwords.

Comment: He has conned me my bitcoins

Comment: Unfortunately that is the case, sorry for your losses. In the future do not EVER share your password, login info, wallet backup, seed phrase, private key, etc, with someone that you do not trust 100%. Anyone asking you for that info is almost certainly running a scam / trying to steal your money. At this point, transfer any remaining BTC out of that wallet, and never use that wallet ever again. I've seen this scam before, I expect the scammer copied your seed phrase down and made a second copy of your wallet, so any BTC you send to that wallet now will be immediately stolen by the scammer.

Answer (score 4):

> **How can I get a private key for this address**

There is essentially no way.

> **Is it possible for me to withdraw my bitcoin I invested here? I don't have the private key**

No.

---

It looks like you fell for a common scam.

- [I've been asked to share wallet credentials to participate in mining. Is that a scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66934/13866)
- [my money gone from wallet scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/73817/13866)
- [BTC Stolen from Blockchain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/68697/13866)
- ["Hidden Wallet" onion site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/70551/13866)
- [Recovering the private key from a blockchain wallet address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72746/13866)
- [Where do I obtain private keys?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/72609/13866)

About watch-only addresses (some of these are also probably victims of this type of scam)

- [Watch only wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/67253/13866)
- [how do I transfer from watch only wallet to my other wallets](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/53598/13866)
- [blockchain account has watch onl on i](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/54488/13866)
- [I have watched addresses in my wallet..how do i use them?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74024/13866)
- [To generate private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/71269/13866)
- [Unable to get private key for Blockchain wallet](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/64914/13866)

Answer (score 1):

Please note, you should never pay for a Blockchain Wallet private key. To receive a bitcoin, you only need to provide the sender with a bitcoin address from your wallet.

I'm sorry to hear about the experience you've had. Very unfortunately, scammers as of late have been taking advantage of users new to the cryptocurrency space and their potential lack of knowledge about private keys, as well as some of our wallet's features. Our wallet can NOT be used for mining, and should NEVER be purchased, created or accessed by a third party. Any person or party claiming otherwise should be considered malicious and avoided. If another party has EVER had access to the wallet, then it should be considered unsafe and never used to store funds. This is because any funds added to or stored within such a wallet could still be compromised using its Backup Phrase, despite any changes made to the password or two factor authentications enabled.

Please be aware, within our wallet a public bitcoin address can be imported into the wallet as 'Watch Only or Non-spendable funds'. This can be done with absolutely any address on the entire bitcoin network. This feature is often used by those who may have paper wallets, or addresses stored within other wallets as a way to still see and track funds without actually importing the bitcoin address's Private Key into our wallet. The balance of addresses imported as 'Watch Only or Non-spendable funds', will NOT show up as part of the wallet's main balance, since without the private key to this address these funds are non-spendable.

- A private key is a string of data that shows you have access to bitcoins in a specific address. Think of a private key like a password specific to each address. Private keys are generated, and stored within the wallet which was used to create the bitcoin address. Private keys must never be shared, as they allow the owner to spend the bitcoins from the associated bitcoin address through its cryptographic signature.

Without a private key, you do not have ownership of an address or access to any funds it may contain. Scammers have been using this feature in a malicious manner to trick those unaware of how private keys work, and their requirement for sending funds.