# Spendable Wallet

Tags: wallet, fraud

My friend ask me to open a wallet in blockchain and ask me to give the ID and password later he transact certain amount of btc which shows non spendable after which I am asked to change my password and finished 2FA then I was asked to deposit some btc in my wallet to create a transactions history so that non spendable can be made spendable so is it a scam

Comment: Can't add much more to it. NEVER EVER give anyone access to your wallet EVER. Unless it's already gone to hell and you're attempting to pay/beg someone to help you recover it. In that scenario never put money into that wallet again. Once you regain access, move anything into it to a new wallet. Remember, the owner of the wallet is the person who has the ability to create a transaction and move amounts away from it.

Comment: See also linked questions in answer to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/74362/13866

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a scam, and a well known one. You will lose all money that you deposit to that wallet, even if only you have the password and 2FA for the wallet. Your "friend" already copied the recovery seed and can take the money from the wallet even without a password or 2FA. Simply stop corresponding with that person.