# Payout query in Mining

Tags: pool-payout-methods

If a miner account is in active , possible to get payout in halving automatically? Bcoz my mining account is active, but cannot access. Possible to get my profit in halving ? My wallet is fused with mining. Please give details. Thanking you.

Comment: What do you mean by 'miner account is active', and 'wallet is fused with mining'? Do you own and run ASIC hardware? Based on what you've written, it sounds like you may be victim of a common 'mining scam'.

Comment: Hi sir, thanku for kind answer. I don't know ASIC Hardware. Mining machine is also not my own.i done a small investment near 75$ in my wallet. To my fb friend. Now he says 20000$ in my account.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry to say it sounds like you are the victim of a scam. That isn't how mining works at all. Did the 'fb friend' ever ask to have access to your wallet login, or tell you to import a watch-only bitcoin address to the wallet? For examples of other users falling for this scam, see: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-can-i-get-a-private-key-for-this-address/74384#74384

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a private key for this address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/74362/how-can-i-get-a-private-key-for-this-address)